# how to retrieve image dimensions before uploading it cloudinary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, dimensions, cloudinary

I need to validate image dimensions before uploading it to `cloudinary` as I am using direct uploading from the form.

```
$(".cloudinary-fileupload").fileupload(
# disableImageResize: false,
imageMinWidth : 460
imageMinHeight: 230
acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpeg|png|bmp|ico)$/i,
maxFileSize: 2097152,
processalways: (e,data) ->
if (data.files.error)
alert(data.files[0].error)

# dropZone: "#direct_upload"
start: (e) ->
$(".status").text "Starting upload..."
return
progress: (e, data) ->
$(".status").text "Uploading... " + Math.round((data.loaded * 100.0) / data.total) + "%"
return
fail: (e, data) ->
$(".status").text "Upload failed"
return
```

this is my jquery file that is used for uploading ....

and this is the view file that is used for uploading the image to cloudinary...

```
<%= cl_image_upload_tag(:image_id,
:html => {:id => "resource_image", :class => "hidden"},

:tags => "directly_uploaded",
:crop => :scale,
:maxFileSize => 2048,
:resource_type => "image",
:format => 'jpg',
:cloudinarydone => true,
:notification_url => new_image_url

) %>
```

kindly tell me, how to achieve the desired functionality as i want an image to be uploaded if its dimensions are more than `460` by `230` otherwise generate an alert for the user to change the picture he selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the dimensions when uploading a local file using jQuery file upload.
You should bind to `fileuploadprocessalways` with the following:

```
function (e, data) {     
 var width = data.img.width;
 var height = data.img.height;
}
```

You need to also include all extra JS libraries required by jQuery file upload and probably turn on some jQuery file upload options, like:

```
previewThumbnail: false
previewMaxWidth: 1000
previewMaxHeight: 1000
```

Comment: fileuploadprocessalways: (e, data) ->
      width = data.img.width
      height = data.img.height
      console.log height // this is my coffee script file and i am using your code but on console it stilld doesnt print any height and moreover when placed in progress function it says cannot get the propertly of undefined.

Comment: You should make sure all the relevant libraries are included. See: https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_js#client-side-image-resizing-before-upload